# selenium python webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

i am trying to loop through 42 sites ..
the script works fine for like 4-5 sites.. sometimes 3 sites.. some it reaches till no 15 site.. then i get an error given in the picture.

my code is given below:

import time

import requests

from selenium import webdriver

sites = []

userid=[]

password=[]

settings=[]

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")

print(len(sites))

print(len(userid))

print(len(password))

print(len(settings))

count=5

for x in range(len(sites)):

```
try:

    requests.get(sites[x])

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

    driver.get(sites[x])

    inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("user_login")

    inputElement.send_keys(userid[x])

    inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("user_pass")

    inputElement.send_keys(password[x])

    inputElement.submit()

    link = driver.find_element_by_id('menu-plugins')

    link.click()

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="'+settings[x]+'"]').click()

    driver.find_element_by_id('save_and_import').click()

    count=count+2

    time.sleep(count)

    driver.quit()

except requests.ConnectionError:

    print(sites[x]+"DOWN !!")

    continue
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEYtj.png)

Comment: Just move all the code into the `try` block and `except` everything. That way it can continue.

Comment: did that but same error persists

Comment: did you put try and except within for loop?

Comment: Ok, just update the code so we can see what you're doing. Remember to use the code formatter (it looks like this: {})

Comment: i upadted the code..still same error..can this be because of cloud flare or chrome driver bug ?

Comment: @GigaByte yes did that buddy